# Reactjs not rendering data from database

Tags: reactjs, axios, mobx

I am learning React. I am facing an weird problem which should be very easy. My goal is to get data from an api and show the data in a table. Please be informed that i am using Mobx to manage my data.

My problem is react is receiving the data from api but not rendering the data.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Mystore from "../Storage/Mystore";
import { Table, Thead, Tbody, Tr, Th, Td } from 'react-super-responsive-table'
import 'react-super-responsive-table/dist/SuperResponsiveTableStyle.css'
import axios from "axios";
import {observer} from "mobx-react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
class ElementSelect extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            element_type: Mystore.element_select.element_type,
            element_list:[]
        }
        //this.return_row = this.return_row.bind(this);
        Mystore.page.title = "Select Element";
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.post('http://localhost/phoenix/public/api/get_element', 
          {
            client_id: Mystore.user_info.client_id,
            element_type: Mystore.element_select.element_type,
            problem_category: Mystore.element_select.problem_category
          })
          .then(response=>{
            if(response.status === 200){
                this.setState({element_list: response.data.data});
            }
            console.log(this.state);
            //console.log(Mystore.element_select.element_list);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });

          console.log("State");
          console.log(this.state);
    }

    render() {

        return <div className="card padding-5">
        <Table>

        <Thead>

                {
                        <Tr>
                            <Th>Link Name ID</Th>
                            <Th>Link ID</Th>
                            <Th>Vlan ID</Th>
                            <Th>District</Th>
                            <Th>Link Name NTTN</Th>
                            <Th>Link Name Gateway</Th>
                            <Th>Ticket List</Th>
                            <Th>Action</Th>
                        </Tr>

                }


        </Thead>
        <Tbody>


            {
                        this.state.element_list.map(
                            element => {
                                <Tr>
                                    <Td>{element.link_name_id}</Td>
                                    <Td>{element.link_id}</Td>
                                    <Td>{element.vlan_id}</Td>
                                    <Td>{element.district}</Td>
                                    <Td>{element.link_name_nttn}</Td>
                                    <Td>{element.link_name_gateway}</Td>
                                    <Td>{element.OPT} {element.SPT}</Td>
                                    <Td><button>Select Element</button></Td>
                                </Tr>

                            }
                        )         
            }

        </Tbody>
        </Table>
        </div>;
    }
}

export default withRouter(observer(ElementSelect));
```

My data loads perfectly. If i print the state in console i can see the data as well. But the data is not rendered in the view.

I tried moving out the code inside array.map to a function. then call that function to return a row. But it did not work.

I also tried loading the data in my Mobx state and render data from that Mobx state. Still it did not work.

I am wondering if Mobx's HOC is some how messing up or Not.

I have no idea why a simple thing like this is not working.

Comment: Yiu are mutating the state. Try var new_state = {... this.state} instead of var new_state = this.state;

Comment: make sure you are getting data. once put a debugger inside ```if``` condition and check.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(response.status === 200){
    this.setState({element_list: response.data.data);
 }
```

you are trying to mutate the state, one try this.

This article may help you [enter link description here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5).

Comment: I changed the code according to your suggestion.. see the update. But its still not working

Comment: Can post sandbox link here?

Comment: make sure you are getting data. once put a debugger inside if condition and check.